# A function linear in a matrix

Tags: matrices, functions

When we say a function $f:\mathbf{R}^{m\times n}\rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ is linear in a matrix $X\in \mathbf{R}^{n \times m}$, does that mean the function is linear in the elements of $X$, i.e., linear in $x_{11},...x_{nm}$?

Comment: I'd have said simply "yes", but that's not enough characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must obey $f(kX+lY)=kf(X)+lf(Y)$, where $X,Y$ are matrices and $k,l$ real scalars.

Comment: I see in a lot of textbooks that (at least from my understanding) in their examples they use the two definitions interchangeably? Is it possible? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Adicionaly, for each pair of indexes one also gets $f(kX_{ij}+lY_{ij})=kf(X_{ij})+lf(Y_{ij})$

Comment: Makes sense now! Thanks!